# Error When Passing Snapshot Data to Class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to pass `Snapshot` data to a new class but I got an error (see below). I tried to add `Snapshot[index]` and I got the error again, but I don't know why.
I am using [`cloud_firestore`](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore).

The Code is:

```
Container(
                height: 171,
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('offers').snapshots(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('${snapshot.error}');
                    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                      case ConnectionState.waiting:
                        return new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
                      default:
                        return new SingleItem(doucment: snapshot,);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              )
```

the SingleItem class is

```
class SingleItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final doucment;
  SingleItem({this.doucment});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Container(
        width: 251,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey[300], blurRadius: 3.0),
          ],
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              bottom: 20,
              right: 120,
              child: Container(
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/camera.png",
                  width: 121,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "${doucment.data['name']}",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "\$ 39.99",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Text(
                    "Ends in 02:00:25",
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error Console is

```
Class 'AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>'
Tried calling: []("name")
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling

```
Firestore.instance.collection('offers').snapshots()
```

you are retrieving a list, not only a single document. So what you want is something like this:

```
Text("${doucment.data.documents[index]['name']}",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
```

Comment: There is an error when i try to pass index documents[index]

Comment: Well, you are trying to show a list within a single element. You can use 0 as index for testing purposes but should either decide on which document you want to show or use a ListView to show all of them.

Comment: in Streambuilder widget when return to new SingleItem(doucment: snapshot[index]) got error

Comment: snapshot.data[index]

Comment: Is the error the same error when when you try to do `snapshot[index]`?

Comment: @Jack Now its work , I shoud try return new SingleItem(doucment: snapshot.data,);

Comment: @Jack sorry for late respond.